# Condicionales sobrescribir base de datos c#

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un programa el cual recibo datos de unos equipos mediante Modbus, de estos equipos recibo dos valores: valores instantáneos de medida y valores acumulados, el problema es que estos equipos resetean su valor acumulado si pierde la alimentación (corte de luz por ejemplo) y necesito almacenar los valores acumulados en una base de datos por si se me presenta este imprevisto. Había puesto en práctica lo siguiente:

```
      private void sobrescibirTotal()
      {
            int totalBBDD = int.Parse(lvDatos.Items[0].SubItems[8].Text); //total BBDD
            int totalAlmacenado;  //total del equipo

            if (int.TryParse(lbMtotal1.Text, out totalAlmacenado))
            {
                if (totalBBDD > totalAlmacenado)
                {
                    int totalReal = totalBBDD + totalAlmacenado;
                    CN.Open();


                    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("UPDATE DATOSconf SET TOTAL = '" + totalReal + "' where ID = 1 ", CN);

                    CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    CN.Close();
                    conexionBBDD();


                    this.dATOSconfTableAdapter1.Fill(this.bBDDconfiguracionesDataSet1.DATOSconf);
                }
                else
                {
                    CN.Open();


                    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("UPDATE DATOSconf SET TOTAL = '" + totalAlmacenado + "' where ID = 1 ", CN);

                    CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    CN.Close();

                    this.dATOSconfTableAdapter1.Fill(this.bBDDconfiguracionesDataSet1.DATOSconf);
                    conexionBBDD();

                }



            }else
            {
                lbMtotal1.Text = "SIN CONEXIÓN";
            }
       }
```

Mi problema es que si realizo esta función al inicio del programa ( el programa no va a correr 24 horas pero los equipos si) o cada vez que mi conexión con el equipo se estabilice, si tengo un valor total del equipo mas pequeño que el de la BBDD se va a sobreescribir siempre el valor de la BBDD con la suma de los dos valores, sin conseguir el valor REAL verdadero. La idea sería algún método que me permita comprobar si el campo de la base de datos se ha actualizado antes con la suma de los dos valores o algo así, nose... Si alguien se le ocurre algo sería de gran ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Guarda en la base de datos ademas del valor que te llega la hora a la que la has guardado y ya de paso el equipo de donde te llega. Luego comparando la informacion que te llegue con la que tengas guardada en base de datos ya podras decidir que hacer

Comment: voy a estudiarlo, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar rowversion en tú tabla DatosConf, y conforme a si el valor que tengas en memoria de rowVersion ha cambiado, ya sabes si el registro se ha actualizado o no.
Hoy he escrito un escenario que podría ser muy similar a lo que planteas. Puedes echarle un ojo al artículo y a ver si encaja con lo que necesitas.
[RowVersion Saber si un registro se ha modificado](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/12/11/rowversion-o-su-alias-timestamp/)

Comment: voy a estudiarlo, gracias.